# Adapter shows items sometimes

Tags: android, baseadapter

I have two BaseAdapter, one for posts and other for answers to the posts. The first one works good and shows the items. When I press to see the answers of a post another Adapter does the work (the AnswerAdapater):

```
public AdapterAnswers(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    this.context=context;
    searchArrayList=list;
    inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
}
 @Override
public int getCount() {
    if (searchArrayList != null)
        return searchArrayList.size();
    else return 5;
}


 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    dataofaRow = searchArrayList.get(position);
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false); 
        Log.d("Converview", "null" + view.getTag());

    }
    TextView comment= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_comment);
    comment.setText(dataofaRow.get(TAG_POSTTEXT));
    return view;}
```

I set the Adapter to the listview in onCreate() of Answers activity:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id=extras.getString("id");

    ReadAnswers readAnswers=new ReadAnswers();
    answerData=readAnswers.returnparam(id);

    adapter=new AdapterAnswers(this,answerData);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The other adapter (MyAdapter) is basically the same:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    this.context=context;
    searchArrayList=list;
    inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
public int getCount() {
    if (searchArrayList != null)
        return searchArrayList.size();
    else return 5;
}
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    dataofaRow = searchArrayList.get(position);

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false); // <-- parent as second argument

    }
    TextView comment= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_comment);
seeAnswers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataofaRow = searchArrayList.get(position);
            String idOfComment=dataofaRow.get(TAG_ID);
            Intent intent=new Intent(context, Answers.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", idOfComment);
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    return view;}
```

And I set the listview in the same way.

```
 ReadPosts redPosts=new ReadPosts();
    allTheData=redPosts.returnparam("Request all the data");
    myAdapter= new MyAdapter(this,allTheData);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

My problem is that just a few times this Adapter works. The problem started when I move the server from a localhost to a web host.
This Adapter doesn't show the items because it doesn't call to the getView, because ArrayList appears as size 0. But when I log the other Adapter also the size is 0 but actually it works well (the post Adapter).

When I change the inflate R.layout.comment_item to another it works for the first time (but not always).
The problem is weird and I've tried a lot of things. Any help is very welcome!

Comment: where you are setting adapter

Comment: Can you please describe your Question as it's require more detail to Understand. Describe both adapters and place where u set both adapter to the List.

Comment: sorry, I hope now is better

Answer (score 0):

**Replace this code with your adapter class**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(converView == null){
       viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_item, parent, false); 

       viewHolder.comment = (Textview) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_comment);
       viewHolder.comment.setTag(position);

       convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
       viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

       viewHolder.comment.setText(dataofaRow.get(TAG_POSTTEXT));
       return convertView();
    }

    private class ViewHolder{
        TextView comment;
    }
```